# How to show custom 404 error page when using `AllowEncodedSlashes On`

Tags: apache, .htaccess, configuration, http-status-code-404

I recently came across the `AllowEncodedSlashes` Apache directive:

https://intranet.csc.liv.ac.uk/manual/mod/core.html#AllowEncodedSlashes

If I hit a URL like this: `www.domain.com/my/page/%2F/etcetera`, Apache shows its default 404 error page:

[image]

However, I would like to return a custom 404 error page but how can I do it within my `.htaccess`? This doesn't work:

ErrorDocument 404 /entrypoint.php

I know I can do it if I have access to the server's `httpd.conf` configuration file (I tested locally). But what if I do not have access to the configuration on a remote site? Is there a way?

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: What is the location of your custom error page?

Comment: `www.domain.com/entrypoint.php`